# Stack-snippet breaks due to HTML syntax issue

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I recently came across this surprising issue with Stack-Snippets.

The snippet below is a perfectly normal scenario where the syntax of both
HTML and JavaScript is correct, and it runs as expected.

```js
alert("Javascript works.");
```

```html
<div>Some content</div>
```

However, if you just removed the very last character in the HTML, i.e. the closing bracket `>` of the closing `</div>` tag, it doesn't render correctly. Specifically, instead of running the JavaScript code as JavaScript, the browser prints it on screen.<sup>(1)(2)(3)</sup>

```js
alert("Javascript works.");
```

```html
<div>Some content</div
```

---

It seems like the browser is trying to *guess* the correct syntax of resulting HTML document, and it fails to do so. So the issue could be considered a [status-by-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-by-design) of the browser.

I am marking this as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) considering that even if it may be caused because of the design of browsers, the behaviour may still perplex new/inexperienced users (given there are no obvious errors), and prevent them from being able to create MCVE.

---

<sup>(1) Here's how it appears to me on [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHouH.png) and [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHibM.png).</sup>

<sup>(2) I tested the same HTML markup and JavaScript on JSFiddle.net, and it also fails partially. You can see the snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmqycddm/</sup>

<sup>(3) Surprisingly, CodePen survives this: https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/VrayGy</sup>

Comment: The script is inserted at the end of the body, right? If so, the behavior you're seeing is caused by the script start tag being eaten up by the incomplete div end tag.

Comment: @BoltClock Yup, I did check that in the Dev tools (F12). That's why I tagged  it as [feature-request].

Comment: To the downvoters, the behaviour of invalid HTML is well-defined by the HTML5 spec, and not practically an error condition any more. It would be nice if these cases could be handled properly, though obviously not as a high priority.

Comment: Why should this markup be *fixed* by StackSnippets? It is an error/typo the author made. This is normal behavior for it to be broken. Fixing such typos for authors may invalidate typos they really have in code.

Comment: @JeremyBanks and where does StackSnippet's behavior differ from the specs? StackSnippet doesn't parse the content, your browser does. All StackSnippet does is to deliver what the author wrote. In this case, it does handle this task correctly.

Comment: @Kaiido: Because it results in unexpected behavior that can only be reproduced in very specific circumstances. Stack Snippets places the script content at the end of the body, which the author isn't going to expect or assume unless they're already used to using that technique on their own sites. You aren't going to reproduce this behavior in a true MCVE (e.g. a blank page or a data URI) unless you explicitly place your script element at the end of the body like Stack Snippets does.

Comment: @BoltClock but an un-closed tag will break the doc, except if it were the last characters of the document. IMO auto-fixing it is plain wrong. StackSnippets should stick to its work: deliver author content as he wrote it.

Comment: @Kaiido Also we are not talking about fixing the typo. I was really hoping for something like Tiny Giant's answer that prevents the HTML syntax issue from affecting the JavaScript processing.

Comment: @Kaiido: And this post is saying Stack Snippets is not doing that job right.

Comment: @BoltClock why? Then should we also say that it doesn't do its job right because if I type in *javascript*  `document.getElementById(XXX)` it does return the correct element while when I paste it in my head's script it returns null? OP made a typo, stacksnippet is not responsible for this typo, and it should simply be fixed by OP. But let's agree we'll disagree here.

Comment: For those who don't understand what I'm talking about, compare `data:text/html,<script>alert("Javascript works.");</script><div>Some content</div` with `data:text/html,<div>Some content</div<script>alert("Javascript works.");</script>`. The latter is how Stack Snippets renders your HTML and JS. If this is what most authors expect, then nothing needs to be changed. If this is *not* what most authors expect from *an MCVE*, then Stack Snippets needs to be changed to behave closer to author expectations if it wants to be The Premier Tool for Producing JavaScript/HTML/CSS MCVEs™.

Comment: When even *JSFiddle* runs the user JS as expected, is there any wonder people still rely on it over Stack Snippets? (I personally only use Stack Snippets when I know that any of its differences from a plain page will not result in unexpected behavior, which, granted, is 99% of use cases, but [I have not shied away from using data URIs for HTML snippets where appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+data%3Atext%2Fhtml).)

Comment: Speaking of 99% of use cases, I should of course point out that such a typo as an unclosed tag - if it is part of the actual markup and not a copy error - would be subject to closure and deletion anyway, but that doesn't change the fact that Stack Snippets demonstrably does not behave as some might expect of an MCVE.

Comment: @BoltClock saying that it does work in jsfiddle is not the thruth. It does work because jsfiddle does **By default** wrap the script content in an onload event, if you choose to place js in the body, then it also fails, with some other output: https://jsfiddle.net/snu5v6oe/ Yes I think the majority of us do expect the script to run after the HTML part has been parsed, otherwise we would have to have the same options as jsfiddle, i.e wrap in head, wrap in onload, wrap in body. But that's an other FR that I wouldn't downvote.

Comment: @Kaiido: Ha, I totally forgot about that. That only *further cements* my point about fiddling tools deviating from what people would expect from an MCVE.

Comment: @Kaiido Regarding your earlier point about having scripts placed in *head* tag, that is indeed allowed with StackSnippets. I've seen many users do that as well. Of course, contrary to their expectation the script tag runs at the top of the body tag, rather than in the head tag (possibly in accordance with the syntax error handling specs that Jeremy mentions). Yet the script should run more-or-less the way the OP intends it to run as rest of the DOM has not loaded when the script runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer identifies a possible fix for the Stack Overflow developers. This is not intended as a workaround, as the logical thing to do in such cases would be to correct the typo.

#### Place an HTML comment between the two sections.

```js
alert("Javascript works.");
```

```html
<div>Some content</div
<!-- -->
```