# Stack Snippets that assign `var location` at the top scope redirect and produce “Server Error in '/' Application.”

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Look at the snippet below. It's a perfectly normal snippet (look at the markdown if you don't believe me). It's not working.

```js
var location = {
  map: {
    geo: "20.471884,-157.5056",
    p: "Hawaii"
  }
};

const [lat, lng] = map.geo.split(",");
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

<del>How is this happening, and</del> how do we fix it?

This is due to the `location` overriding `window.location`. How could we fix this? Should we update the Stack Snippets engine to allow these variable names? Maybe using an IIFE as suggested would fix the issue.

Comment: That’s what happens when you [assign `location` in the global scope in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46029296/4642212). Use `const location`, scope it in a function or use a different variable name. This answers the _“How is this happening”_, but the _“how do we fix it”_ remains.

Comment: Apparently `const location` doesn’t necessarily work.

Comment: If we wrapped everything in IIFEs it would invalidate several questions about this very issue. I think, stack snippets should be about Minimal, _complete_ and verifiable examples or Minimal _reproducible_ examples. The code in this snippet wouldn’t work in a real application, so why should it work in the snippet? How often does this even happen?

Comment: The Stack Snippet backend could be modified to show a friendlier _“The snippet has been redirected to `/[object Object]`”_ note rather than a _“Server Error in '/' Application.”_ message. This would also make legitimate uses of `window.location` not look like an error.

Comment: Long story short: Avoid `var` ...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's due to the `var location`, which assigns to `window.location` and attempts to replace the page. But you assigned an object to `location`, resulting in a request to

```
https://stacksnippets.net/[object%20Object]
```

which doesn't exist, of course, resulting in the "Server Error in '/' Application.".

Use a different variable name

```js
var loc = {
  map: {
    geo: "20.471884,-157.5056",
    p: "Hawaii"
  }
};

const [lat, lng] = loc.map.geo.split(",");
console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);
```

or put it in an IIFE

```js
(() => {
  var location = {
    map: {
      geo: "20.471884,-157.5056",
      p: "Hawaii"
    }
  };

  const [lat, lng] = location.map.geo.split(",");
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lng);
})();
```

(semi-related: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385452/reassigning-window-name-inside-a-stack-snippet-results-in-unexpected-popup) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776759/how-to-avoid-accidentally-implicitly-referring-to-properties-on-the-global-objec))

I suppose this could be fixed by Stack Overflow by automatically wrapping Javascript snippet code in an IIFE, eg, from this markdown:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    // Javascript here
    // More Javascript here

<!-- end snippet -–>
```

generate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">(function() {
        // Javascript here
// More Javascript here
    })();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Javascript here
// More Javascript here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That would also fix the `window.name` problem in the other question, though it would make a few questions resulting from `window` shenanigans not reproducible in the snippet console.

Unfortunately, `window.location` is not configurable, so it couldn't even theoretically be overwritten so as to throw an error if the user tries to assign to it.

Comment: Kaiido suggestion could solve the _`window` shenanigans_ by allowing multiple snippets modes: like one mode where it keeps the current behavior, and another mode where the JS is wrapped in an IIFE. We already have a parameter to show or hide the console, so having a parameter to embed in IIFE or not sounds like a reasonable addition.

Comment: I quite like the IIFE idea - a feature request wouldn't go unnoticed.

Comment: @JamesCoyle I'm not seeing what the additional parameter would accomplish - `window` is accessible regardless, it being a parameter doesn't prevent properties from being able to be implicitly referenced (eg `const foo = location`), and while declared variables could not conflict with window properties, the same would be true regardless in the IIFE regardless of argument, right?

Comment: One bigger concern about this IIFE auto-wrapping than "shenanigans": all the `onevent` attribute would break. Ok, that's bad practice, but unfortunately still frequent in many beginner tutorials, and of course here too. Moreover, since they are generally new to web-dev, the ones posting this will have even harder time to understand why their code breaks at a different place here than anywhere else with a confusing *eventhandler is undefined* error message when they'd have correctly written it in their code => They'll think SO is broken.

Comment: @Kaiido That's a great point, and is the same issue many have with JSFiddle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/why-isnt-my-javascript-working-in-jsfiddle An implicit IIFE might well cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 15):

This has already [been brought before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358863/stack-snippet-breaks-due-to-html-syntax-issue).
The only thing that Stack-Snippets do wrong here is that it's not very clear what the structure of the generated document is.

And the only "solution" I can think of would be to add an option *à la jsfiddle* to set different modes of script inclusion.

- "no wrap in head",
- "no wrap in body" [current],
- "wrap in load event handler".

IMO, any other solution would be at least as much confusing as is the current behavior.

Comment: And then two people add the same answer with two different "snippet modes" using a global variable, one works one doesn't ... IMO thats even more confusing.

Comment: @JonasWilms why would it be? I never said this option should not be visible from the post.